# Create backups of eclipse projects

Tags: php, eclipse, project-management, backup, eclipse-pdt

Is it possible to backup an entire eclipse PDT project (or parts of it), so that it can be restored to that state later?

Ideally this would only save changes from the last backup to save space. If it makes any difference I have Mylyn installed (Maybe you could backup the current task context?) and am using CodeIgniter.

Thanks,

Lemiant

Comment: Ummm...  Do you mean source control?  (Such as SVN or GIT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to look into version control. There are many options, the most popular of which are [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). The latter two are probably along the lines of what you're looking for.

It is generally good practice to use version control for projects of any real size.